# How to set a view's color to match a translucent navigation bar's color?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationbar, uicolor

I need to increase the height of the navigation bar. For this, I have added a view (of desired height) under the navigation bar. The navigation bar is set to be **translucent**. So the nav bar color is rendered slightly different than the actual hex value. Now I need to match the navigation bar's color to the view below. Following is the code that I am using.

```
func setupNavigationBar() {
    title = "Profile"

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: ""), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "")

    headerView.backgroundColor = navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
    headerView.isOpaque = false  
}
```

I am getting different shades as below.

[image]

How can i make the view's color to be the same as navigation bar's color? I can get near to the desired color by reducing the view's alpha but I am doubtful about that approach since there is no standard defined regarding it.

P.S. The navigation bar has to stay translucent.

Comment: make navigation bar clear color

Comment: The best solution for such a use case where you want to have a navigation bar with customizable height is to create a custom navigation bar (using UIView ot something else) and implement the transitions yourself. This is because even if you manage to match the color with navigation bar with your view, there will be cases when iOS navigation bar will animate (fade in or cross fade) during transitions and your view won't which will result in bad user experience.

Comment: @kerry I will consider the point you have mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set `opacity` of `headerView` to `0.85`

```
headerView.backgroundColor = navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
headerView.layer.opacity = 0.85
headerView.isOpaque = false
```

[image: Output]

[You can download the sample code from here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1crGQnKM88KlIbU4JE7xuPp4FTiyURik8):

Please ignore other unused code in the sample code.

## Explanation:

When you're set `navigationController` style as `translucent` then the system automatically take layer opacity `0.85` for `UINavigationController`

I personally check it by `iterating` all subview of `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I am still not able to get same colors with this solution. How did you set the color for navigation bar? I am setting the hex value in the storyboard.

Comment: I am doing the same thing. Wait I'm sharing demo code with you. Thanks

Comment: just uncheck translucent from navbar inspector and don't change the opacity

Answer (score 0):

Set the background colour to clear for the navigation bar using :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color to nil and it will follow the background color.

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance() 
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground() 
appearance.backgroundColor = nil

navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = 
appearance 

navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance
```